# How to Audio Mp3 file convert to XML file in NodeJS Or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm facing the problem I'm not able to convert audio mp3 file to XML file in NodeJS

i want to mp3 file convert to XMl file using NodejS or JavaScript

Comment: What do you want to do? Convert the binary blob into a base 64 string and put into an XML document? You want an XML document from the file's metadata? Please clarify

Comment: audio mp3 file to XML file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which Package Should I use ...mp3 file convert to XML file